# How to upload a video from a website in PHP and add it to a You Tube Channel?

Tags: php, web-applications, web, youtube-data-api

I am developing a website in PHP . In my website there is a feature where general users can upload their talented videos, and the videos must get uploaded to company’s youtube channel .. is it possible ?? If yes ..then how it can be made possible .

I am using the code which i got from youtube 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

I already created a project in google console and enabled the API

How do I obtain these?

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = ‘REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = ‘REPLACE_ME';
```

I also wanted to know about  authorized redirect URI which i found in the web application section of this link.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register#Create_OAuth2_Tokens